# Angular is ignoring the style class set on less files

Tags: html, css, angular, less

For some reason my Angular app doesn't use the styles I'm defining at my component's .less file. It simply ignore it.

As I am very newbie with CSS, I don't any way to debug it.

My layout is consisted by a lot of defined styles being imported by other less files. I am using trying to modify the style of a mapboxgl.

This is how the map current looks like:

[image]

And it's defined on HTML by:

```
<div eds-tile class="column xl-3">
    <eds-tile-title>Location</eds-tile-title>
    <eds-tile-actions>
        <div class="action">
            <eds-icon icon="maximize">
            </eds-icon>
        </div>
    </eds-tile-actions>
    <div class="map" id="map"></div>
</div>
```

On this component's less I have:

```
@import "~@eds/vanilla/variables/light";
@import (reference) "~@eds/vanilla/font/styles";
@import (reference, multiple) "~@eds/vanilla/variables/global";
@import "./map/map";
```

And on ./map/map.less I have a lot of theme stylization:
https://pastebin.com/b8CpakH9

My trouble is that there's some classes that are indeed being used by Angular, like this one:

```
.map {
  min-height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;

  a {
    color: @text;
  }
}
```

[image]

But others are not, like this (you can see on image below that there's nothing related by that definition on browser's styles inspection):

```
.mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-left {
  display: none !important;
}
```

[image]

What is happening on my case?

I'm following another example that it's working fine. On the component.less file it uses:

```
@import (reference) "~@eds/vanilla/font/styles";

.dark {
  @import "~@eds/vanilla/variables/dark";
  @import (multiple) "./map/map";
}
.light {
  @import "~@eds/vanilla/variables/light";
  @import (multiple) "./map/map";
}
```

And the map.less file is the same except the by the min-height value.

The example:

[image]

You can clearly see that on this example it's using ".light .map {}" to set the style. Different that my case, that converts to ".map[_ng-content-c5] {}" for some reason. I don't have any clue of what this means.

Sorry by being so vague about the problem description. It's simply because I'm don't have enough experience even to name it.

Comment: I might have misunderstood but exactly is it you're trying to do?

Comment: did you reference your styles file in angular.json

Comment: it should be ```"styles": [
              "src/filename.less"
            ]
```

Comment: @indrajeet No, it's not this problem. It's indeed using the styles due the theme being displyed, but there's particular things that are not.

Comment: @OnlineUser02094 In this particular case I'm just trying to set display:none on the 'mapbox' link's div, to simply make it disappear, and it's not working. Although I'm showing just this scenario, this behavior is happening on several other cases.

Comment: Maybe you are inside an iframe?

Comment: @cloned No, it's not this problem. I'm not sure enough to say that this is not an iframe, but I'm following another example that it's working fine and I don't know why mine doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I know what the problem is.

If you open your generated css file you see that there is no `.mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-left {`

You will instead see something like: `.mapboxgl-ctrl-bottom-left[_ngcontent...] {`

That's how angular works, it adds some attributes to ensure a style only applies to one component.

You can control if styles are encapsulated or not with [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation)

Most likely this happens because the content (in this case the map) is getting rendered with JS after the DOM is loaded and is not handled by angular itself, therefore it doesn't get the attributes.
Without any more information I can't help you any further since I don't know all the details. I don't know exactly which map you are using, maybe there is a tutorial on how to integrate it with angular somehow.

Comment: Please, see my edit. It's very related to this. Do you know why on that example it doesn't use this "ngcontent" thing (it uses Angular too)?

Comment: Using 'encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None' on @Component solved my problem. Thanks.